# Python parallelisation to repeat a specific function

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, python-multiprocessing

I have a function of parameters I am fitting to data (and so is called many times). the function could be thought of as `F = conv(R1,T1) + conv(R2,T2) + conv(R3,T3)`.

It's not especially important for this what R and T are. The main point is I have to do 3 convolutions (which I do with scipy), so I wanted to do these 3 in parallel to optimise the code. The code below shows how I implement it. This is a simplified example, in the real thing the two functions are more complicated, and I will give them as inputs to f, but the actual scipy convolution step will be identical.

In the full working f will be of the form f(T,R), and may well take further args.

`

```
import time
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
from multiprocessing import Pool

q = np.arange(0,5,0.0001)
theory = np.exp(-1*q)
q2 = np.arange(-5,5,0.0001)
resolution = np.exp(-1/2*(q2**2))

def f( i ):
    return fftconvolve( theory , resolution , mode='same' ) #time.sleep(1)



start = time.time()
f( 0 )
end = time.time()
print(f'Time 0 = { end-start }')



start = time.time()
for i in range(0,3):
    f( i )    
end = time.time()
print(f'Time 1 = { end-start }')



pool = Pool( processes= 3 )
start = time.time()
pool.map( f , [0, 1, 2, ])
end = time.time()
print(f'Time 2 = { end-start }')
```

`

I get:

```
Time 0 = 0.005838155746459961

Time 1 = 0.01575756072998047

Time 2 = 0.028168439865112305
```

I would have assumed that `Time 2` would be a little over 3 times `Time 0`. So something is going wrong.

I get times of: 1,3,1 when I use the commented out time.sleep(3) instead of the convolution, which is what I expect.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this to run in parallel? It may mean using something other Multiprocessing. To be clear what I was aiming for is that the function f is run 3 times (for 3 different set of args) but in parallel, so that the total time is about the same time as just one run of f.

Comment: My guess is that parallelization has a significant overhead, which is not worth the economy it brings when the task is short. You may want to check a larger data arrays `np.arange(0,5,0.000001)` and maybe also insert the generation of such large datasets inside the function itself, so that these global variables don't take time being copied into different processes if it happens. On my laptop `np.arange(0,5,0.000001)` makes time 2 comparable to time 1 (a bit longer).